# Different behavior between development and production

Tags: javascript, outlook-web-addins

I developed a Web Add-In for Outlook for my Company, which will set an E-Mail Header on an outgoing Mail to indicate whether a mail shall be encrypted by the MTA or not. Additionally, there shall be an indicator on the saved outgoing mail, to make it easy for the user to determine if the Mail was encrypted or not.
To archive this, I hook into the OnMessageSend event and simple change the icon and text of a notification.

It works like expected as long I run the Add-In locally in development. But as soon the Add-In is on the Production Server, it does not change the last notification within the OnMessageSend event. The saved mail, from the outgoing folder, still shows the "This Message will be encrypted" notification and not the indicator.
To fix this I tried several tricks like to implement a wait for the event to complete but nothing worked out. The Add-In does not change the indicator notification when put on the production server, just like it does locally in development.

Do maybe someone knows what's the problem here?

This is the Code snipped which will change the Notification on a Mail, when the User click the "Send" Button, based on the Security Settings for this mail:

```
/*
* Copyright (c) R4C GmbH | R4C - Services GmbH. All rights reserved.
* Developed by Harald Swoboda
*/

// When an encrypted message is send by the user, set a persistent notification and icon on it. 
function onMessageSendHandler(event) {
    // Some logging
    console.log("OnSend Event called.");

    // Check if the encryption header is set.
    Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders.getAsync(["x-r4c-encrypt"], { "asyncContext": event }, sendCallback);
}

// Dismiss the users choice of dismissing a notification.
function onInfoBarDismissClickedHandler(event) {
    // Some logging
    console.log("OnInfoBarDismiss Event called.");

    // Check if the encryption header is set.
    Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders.getAsync(["x-r4c-encrypt"], { "asyncContext": event }, dismissCallback);
}

// The OnSend callback function.
function sendCallback(asyncResult) {
    // Get the event pointer from asyncContext.
    let event = asyncResult.asyncContext;

    // If the function was executed successful.
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        // Some logging
        console.log("AsyncResult succeeded.");

        // If we got a value back aka there is our header,...
        if (asyncResult.value) {
            // Some logging
            console.log("x-r4c-encrypt has value. Going to change the Notification...");

            // ..and set a new notification with a own icon to reflect the encryption state on the outgoing mail.
            Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("information", {
                type: "informationalMessage",
                message: "Diese Nachricht wurde Verschlüsselt.",
                icon: "Icon.Cryptmail.16x16",
                persistent: true
                }, function (asyncResult) {
                    console.log("Within the callback!");
                    if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                        console.error("Failed to set Cryptmail Notification: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
                    } else console.log("Cryptmail Notification was set.");
                }
            );

            // Some logging
            console.log("..done!");
        }
    } else {
        // Some logging
        console.error("AsyncResult error!");

        let message = "Ein Fehler ist aufgetrehten: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error);
        event.completed({ allowEvent: false, errorMessage: message });
    }

    // Some logging
    console.log("Closing the event.");

    // Close the event, we are done here.
    event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}

// The OnDismiss callback function.
function dismissCallback(asyncResult) {
    // Get the event pointer from asyncContext.
    let event = asyncResult.asyncContext;
    
    // If the function was executed successful.
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {        
        // If we got a value back aka there is our header,...
        if (asyncResult.value) {
            Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("information", {
                type: "informationalMessage",
                message: "Ihre Nachricht wird Verschlüsselt.",
                icon: "Icon.Lock.16x16",
                persistent: true
            });
        } else {
            Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("information", {
                type: "informationalMessage",
                message: "Verschlüsselung wurde entfernt.",
                icon: "Icon.Unlock.16x16",
                persistent: true
            });
        }
    } else {
        let message = "Ein Fehler ist aufgetrehten: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error);
        event.completed({ allowEvent: false, errorMessage: message });
    }

    // Close the event, we are done here.
    event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}

// Map the event handler name specified in the manifest's LaunchEvent element to its JavaScript counterpart.
if (Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC || Office.context.platform == null) {
    Office.actions.associate("onMessageSendHandler", onMessageSendHandler);
    Office.actions.associate("onInfobarDismissClickedHandler", onInfoBarDismissClickedHandler);
}
```

The log file outcome:

```
01.03.2023 16:25:29 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : 62916641-fc48-44ae-a2a3-163811f1c945, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" : Element Name "TabletSettings", Line=27, CharPosition=8     
01.03.2023 16:25:29 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : 62916641-fc48-44ae-a2a3-163811f1c945, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" : Element Name "PhoneSettings", Line=32, CharPosition=8      
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : f60b8ac7-c3e3-4e42-8dad-e4e1fea59ff7, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" : Element Name "TabletSettings", Line=64, CharPosition=6     
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : f60b8ac7-c3e3-4e42-8dad-e4e1fea59ff7, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" : Element Name "PhoneSettings", Line=68, CharPosition=6      
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : 7a774f0c-7a6f-11e0-85ad-07fb4824019b, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" : Element Name "TabletSettings", Line=69, CharPosition=12        
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : 7a774f0c-7a6f-11e0-85ad-07fb4824019b, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" : Element Name "PhoneSettings", Line=73, CharPosition=12     
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : a216ceed-7791-4635-a752-5a4ac0a5eb93, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" : Element Name "TabletSettings", Line=68, CharPosition=8     
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : a216ceed-7791-4635-a752-5a4ac0a5eb93, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" : Element Name "PhoneSettings", Line=71, CharPosition=8      
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : bc13b9d0-5ba2-446a-956b-c583bdc94d5e, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" : Element Name "TabletSettings", Line=71, CharPosition=12        
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Monitorable Manifest    Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : bc13b9d0-5ba2-446a-956b-c583bdc94d5e, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" : Element Name "PhoneSettings", Line=75, CharPosition=12     
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Unexpected  Resource    The resource you are trying to use does not exist.      
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Unexpected  SourceMap   Debugging is enabled, but source map file is unavailable. SolutionId=a23718a0-cc34-4e20-b4e3-892d2eb3dbde , AppVersion=1.0.1.0      
01.03.2023 16:25:30 Unexpected  Resource    The resource you are trying to use does not exist.      
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Unexpected  Resource    The resource you are trying to use does not exist.      
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Unexpected  Resource    The resource you are trying to use does not exist.      
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Unexpected  SourceMap   Debugging is enabled, but source map file is unavailable. SolutionId=a23718a0-cc34-4e20-b4e3-892d2eb3dbde , AppVersion=1.0.1.0      
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Platform Bundle - Office exists!        
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Platform Bundle - Office.actions exists!        
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Platform Bundle - Office.actions.associate exists!      
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Outlook Batch JS loaded!        
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Outlook LaunchEvent JS loaded!      
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method.       
01.03.2023 16:27:11 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method.       
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] InvokeMailboxCreateOM was invoked!["{\"hostVersion\":\"16.0.16026.20200\", \"itemType\":4, \"permissionLevel\":3, \"userEmailAddress\":\"harald.swoboda@r4c-services.at\", \"userDisplayName\":\"Harald Swoboda | R4C - Services\", \"userProfileType\":\"office365\", \"userTimeZone\":\"W. Europe Standard Time\", \"conversationId\":null, \"ewsUrl\":\"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx\", \"restUrl\":\"https://outlook.office.com/api\", \"itemNumber\":1073741828, \"roamingSettings\":\"{}\", \"extensionPointType\":8, \"enableBetaAPIs\":false, \"displayLanguage\":\"de-DE\", \"contentLanguage\":\"de-AT\", \"officeVersion\":\"16.0.16026.20200\", \"requirementSets\":\"{\\\"Mailbox\\\":\\\"1.12\\\",\\\"OutlookTelemetry\\\":\\\"1.2\\\",\\\"IdentityAPI\\\":\\\"1.3\\\"}\", \"isFromSharedFolder\":false, \"shouldRunNewCodeForFlags\":1}"]     
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] SDX Control is ready!       
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] OnSend Event called.        
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] MailboxHostExecuteApi invoked!      
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] RunLaunchEventHandlerFunctionWithData was invoked with funcName = onMessageSendHandler      
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] AsyncResult succeeded.      
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] x-r4c-encrypt has value. Going to change the Notification...        
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] MailboxHostExecuteApi invoked!      
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] ..done!     
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Closing the event.      
01.03.2023 16:27:13 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Event completed message sent to host!
```

The Notification when a user click the encrypt button on a mail:
[The Message will be encrypted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT9wt.png)

The Notification of the saved outgoing mail in development:
[This Message was encrypted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trDeC.png)

The Notification of the saved outgoing mail in production:
[The Message will be encrypted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHEgX.png)

Comment: Hi @DevHarry, When you say your add-in is not working in production server, what exactly do you mean? Are you installing the add-in from the store?

Also, is your outlook flagged for development in both cases?

Any more information you could think of to provide would help.

Comment: Hi @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT here some more detailed information:
We run the Add-In from an own server inside the companies' production network. I use an Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 VM running on a Proxmox Hypervisor.
The Website is hosted by Apache2 and the server has additional UFW enabled.
We side load the Add-In from the store via providing a URL for the manifest. My machine is a development one, so also my Outlook is flagged for Development.
But we also tested it on other machines which their Outlooks are not flagged for development and got the same result.

Comment: Hi @DevHarry, Just to confirm a few details -
1. I could have been a bit more clear on my last message - By "flagged for development", I meant if outlook is ready to debug launchevent add-ins by following this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch?tabs=windows) or this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging#runtime-logging-on-windows).
2. To confirm, the add-in is running in both instances (in development server and production server), but production server, it displays the wrong info bar, correct?

Comment: If those details are correct, are you able to confirm that the correct Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync() is being called either by debugging or by logging using the links provided above?

Comment: Hi @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, I changed the code to be more clear and updated the post. Additionally, I added the log file to the post. The behavior changed and where before, the problem only happened on the Production, it is now also present in development mode. Also, I added some debug logging to the code and for what it looks like, the "Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync()" is invoked but not executed. The log messages from the Callback are missing.

Comment: Hi @DevHarry, Can you try moving the event.completed() call to the inside of the callback function that logs the "Within the callback!" message? It's possible that the event.completed() call is executing before the Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync() call is able to properly execute the launchevents

Comment: Hi @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, yup, that did the trick. -.-

Comment: Hi @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, well, awesome. Thank you very much for the support. I had already thought of a timing problem. All in all, for the onSend Event, since it will close the mail item, an additional callback is needed to give the process time to finish.

Comment: Hi @DevHarry, Thank you for the confirmation that it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

event.completed() should be called within the Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync() callback to make sure that the event has truly completed. Otherwise, event.completed() may execute before the api has had a chance to finish processing